# RedBeanPHP how to wrap bean over already existing table?

Tags: php, redbean

I am tying to create API with RedBeanPHP and I have following case:
Have to find all records from table with name "my_data01"

```
R::findAll( 'my_data01' );
```

But my model class have name 'Product.php' which contains of

```
class Product  extends SimpleModel
{
public $attributes = array();

public function dispense() {}

...//other methods
}
```

I want to somehow wrap my table "my_data01" inside bean (may be) 
that has name Product.
and when using code like:

```
R::findAll( 'product' );
```

It will query "my_data01" table.
How can i do that? thnx

---

also a have used `define( 'REDBEAN_MODEL_PREFIX', 'myapp\\' )` for corecctly loadyng model for current bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in RedBean. The ORM is intrinsically linked to its own data structure. I'd suggest importing `my_data01` into a new table called `product`. Indeed, the manual for RedBean states:

> You should also NOT use RedBeanPHP if you don't like the RedBeanPHP
>   schema policies and you want complete control over the layout of your
>   database schema, i.e. the column names used for primary keys and
>   foreign keys.

Your other alternative of course, is to use another ORM which offers more flexibility, for example [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent).